# How to get custom risk attribute in sales order grid

Tags: magento-1.9, order-grid

I'm trying to display the custom  attribute in sales order grid using left join. If I had the joinLeft query I'm getting "No records found in sales order grid"

```
$collection = Mage::getResourceModel($this->_getCollectionClass());
$collection->getSelect()->join(array('customer' => 'customer_entity'), 'customer.entity_id = main_table.customer_id', array('customer.group_id'));
$collection->getSelect()->joinLeft('sales_flat_order_address', 'main_table.entity_id = sales_flat_order_address.parent_id',array('telephone','postcode' ) )->where("sales_flat_order_address.address_type = 'billing'");
$collection->getSelect()->joinLeft(array('mt'=>'sales_flat_order'), 'main_table.entity_id=mt.entity_id', 
    array("partner_orderid"=>"partner_orderid","order_trackingurl"=>"order_trackingurl","payment_status"=>"payment_status", "loan_document_status"=> "loan_document_status","mifos_down_payment" => "mifos_down_payment", "partner_web_flag" => "partner_web_flag"));
$collection->getSelect()->joinLeft(array('orderitem'=>'sales_flat_order_item'), 'main_table.entity_id=orderitem.order_id', 
    array("original_price"=>"original_price","row_invoiced"=>"row_invoiced","name"=>"name"));
$collection->getSelect()->group('entity_id');
$fn = Mage::getModel('eav/entity_attribute')->loadByCode('1', 'mobile');
//$ln = Mage::getModel('eav/entity_attribute')->loadByCode('1', 'college_name');
**$nf = Mage::getModel('eav/entity_attribute')->loadByCode('1', 'grisk_nach_flag');**
$tln = Mage::getModel('eav/entity_attribute')->loadByCode('1', 'grisk_college_new_id');
$customUrl = Mage::getSingleton('eav/config')->getAttribute('catalog_product', 'customer_url');
$collection->getSelect()
    ->joinLeft(array('ce1' => 'customer_entity_text'), 'ce1.entity_id=main_table.customer_id', array('mobile' => 'value'))
    ->where('ce1.attribute_id='.$fn->getAttributeId())
    //->join(array('ce2' => 'customer_entity_varchar'), 'ce2.entity_id=main_table.customer_id', array('college_name' => 'value'))
    // ->where('ce2.attribute_id='.$ln->getAttributeId())
    //->columns(new Zend_Db_Expr("ce1.value AS customer_name,ce2.value AS customer_college"));

    ->joinLeft(array('ce3' => 'customer_entity_int'), 'ce3.entity_id=main_table.customer_id', array('grisk_college_new_id' => 'value'))
    ->where('ce3.attribute_id='.$tln->getAttributeId())

    **->joinLeft(array('ce4' => 'customer_entity_int'), 'ce4.entity_id = main_table.customer_id', array('nach_flag' => 'value'))
    ->where('ce4.attribute_id='.$nf->getAttributeId())**

    ->joinLeft( array('cmps' => 'campus'), 'cmps.id=ce3.value',array('cname' => 'name') )

    ->columns(new Zend_Db_Expr("ce1.value AS customer_name, cmps.name AS customer_college, ce4.value AS customer_nach"))
    ->joinLeft(array('ct' =>'cities'), 'ct.id=cmps.city',  array('city_name'=>'address'));  

//echo $collection->getSelect();
if (!Mage::getSingleton('admin/session')->isAllowed('sales/order/actions/gridview')) {
    $collection->addFieldToFilter('entity_id', 0);
}
$this->setCollection($collection);
```

Comment: Please make this question more readable

Comment: Hi Prakash, In the above query I'm trying to fetch one custom attribute in sales order grid using join query. attribute name is "grisk_nach_flag". If I use joinLeft query it's showing no records found. One more thing here the attribute create using "Risk" magento default function in admin.

Comment: Is your issue solved?